# how to assign a static row at the first and last row of dynamically allocated data in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

i m parsing a json file and populating it in my table view what i want to assign is a static row.at the first and last row of my tableview named as Var tycker du. but doing so.it overlaps the dynamically allocated data from json file..could you guys help me out below is the code.

```
  static NSString * const kCellTextKey = @"CellTextKey";
 static NSString * const kCellStateKey = @"CellStateKey";

 static NSString* kAppId = @"126013844184727";
 #define KFBAccessToken     @"126013844184727"
  #define KFBExpirationDate @"KFBExpirationDate"

  @implementation Tab5

  @synthesize tableview1,jsonData,jsonArray,story,media1,url,descriptiondesc,media2;
  @synthesize arForIPs = _arForIPs;
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
objMan = [[HJObjManager alloc] initWithLoadingBufferSize:6 memCacheSize:20];
self.arForIPs=[NSMutableArray array];


    self.tableview1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.tableview1 setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:TRUE];

jsonurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Api/GetPark? parkid=3"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonurl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
connection1=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

self.jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonurl];

NSDictionary *items=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

items1 = [items objectForKey:@"ThingsTodo"];

story = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];
media1 = [[NSMutableArray array]retain];

url=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
media2=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
descriptiondesc=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
dog=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
arr=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
bose=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
for (NSDictionary *item in items1)
{
    [self.story addObject:[item objectForKey:@"Name"]];
    [self.media1 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"Status"]];
    //[self.media2 addObject:[item objectForKey:@"Image"]];

}

//NSLog(@"room:%@",items1);
[self makeNewArray];


    }


    -(void)makeNewArray
     {
   for ( int i=0; i<[self.media1 count]; i++) 
    {

    NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:i];



    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];
    //NSLog(@"the value:%@",str);

    if([str isEqualToString:@"1"])
    { 
        text = [self.story objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *text1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
        NSNumber *state = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];


     dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text1,kCellTextKey,state,kCellStateKey,nil];
       [arr addObject:dict];



  //  [dog addObject:[self.story objectAtIndex:i]];


    }
    dog=[arr mutableCopy];
      NSLog(@"wat hav i got:%@",arr);  

     }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{

return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 

 {

return [dog count];

 }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    }
 // cell.textLabel.text=[dog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *rowData = [dog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [rowData objectForKey:kCellTextKey];
if ([[rowData objectForKey:kCellStateKey] boolValue]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [bose removeObject:[newDict valueForKey:@"CellTextKey"]];
   // NSLog(@"object going to get removed:%@",bose);
}
sectionRows = [tableview1 numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];



return cell;

  }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *dict = [dog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL newState = ![[dict objectForKey:kCellStateKey] boolValue];
newDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:kCellTextKey],    kCellTextKey, [NSNumber numberWithBool:newState], kCellStateKey, nil];
[dog replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newDict];

[bose addObject:[newDict valueForKey:@"CellTextKey"]];
 NSLog(@"the current added data:%@",bose);
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey try out with this solution

```
-(void)makeNewArray
{
for ( int i=0; i<[self.media1 count]; i++) 
{

    NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];
    //NSLog(@"the value:%@",str);

    if([str isEqualToString:@"1"])
    { 
        text = [self.story objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *text1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];
        NSNumber *state = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];


        dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text1,kCellTextKey,state,kCellStateKey,nil];
        [arr addObject:dict];

        //  [dog addObject:[self.story objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
NSDictionary *dict;

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Var tycker du", @"CellTextKey", 
        @"0", @"CellStateKey", nil];
[dog addObject:dict];
for(int i=0; i<arr.count; i++){
    [dog addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
}


[dog addObject:dict];        
//        dog=[arr mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"wat hav i got:%@",dog);  


}
```